# How to refresh the browser with JS after clicking a link_to tag in a Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, reload, link-to

I'm trying to refresh the browser after the user clicks a link to an action that updates the database.

I want to avoid using redirect_back to prevent being sent back to the top of the screen after reload so I'm adding a JS click listener to the link_to tag with a code like this:

```
# in my view
<h5 class='my-link'><%= link_to 'vote', vote_path' %></h5> 

# at the bottom of my application layout
<script>
  $('.my-link').click(function (event) {
    window.location.reload(true);
  });
</script>
```

The JS code listener works OK in that if I click on any section of the h5 element the page will reload. However, when I click in the link the application will go to the relevant controller#action but the page wont reload.

I'm assuming I'm missing a way to execute first the link action and then force the refresh. So at click the app records a vote and then JS force a reload. Can you see any way I can achieve this? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I some what solved this issue by adding a timer to the JS event so it gives time for the link to reach the controller and do the action and do the reload after it.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.puke-icon, .clean-link, .comment-send').click(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
                   window.location.reload(true); },
             50);
          });

    });
</script>
```

This is probably too hacky so hopefully you can provide more elegant approaches thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `vote controller action`, use `location.reload()` in `respond_to do format`.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
end
```

**View:**

`<h5 class='my-link'><%= link_to 'vote', vote_path' %></h5>`

**Controller:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  def vote
    ----------------------  

    // your code goes here

    ----------------------  

    respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" }
    end

  end

end
```

This will reload the page after the database action is completed.

Comment: Thanks Sravan. I've tried to implement your solution but I'm getting the following error when invoking the posts controller (which has the vote controller on it): ActionController::UnknownFormat. Do you know how this may be the case?

Comment: `<h5 class='my-link'><%= link_to 'vote', vote_path', method: :post, remote: true %></h5>`

Comment: @Andrew, have you tried by changing the above line?

Comment: Great Sravan it works now. Thanks! Not sure exactly how it works but I guess I'll have to do a search about the remote feature and the respond_to. If you have another minute to spare. I have also a comment form in and i'd like to preserve the position as well after posting a comment. I've tried the same approach at comments#create but adding remote: true in the button_tag doesn't get rid of the ActionController::UnknownFormat error. Why could that be the case?

Comment: sure, I m going to lunch, will be back in few minutes. :)

Comment: @Andrew, pls share your issue now.

Comment: Hi Sravan sorry I missed your message earlier. I was trying to apply your solution to avoid the scroll location jumping back to the top of the viewport when submitting a form. I've tried to modify a create action at the comments controller by including format.js {render inline: "location.reload();" } as suggested and adding remote:true in the button_tag without success. I'm currently using my onclick-with-delay-JS solution and it works fine but was wondering how your approach could solve the reload issue when submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.product').click(function () {
 location.reload();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="footerRow">

         <div class="col-xs-12 product">
            <h2>Product</h2>
         <div>
         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but although this would make the page reload after a click in the div this doesn't the link_to tag problem as describe above.